# Convert an online JSON set of files to a relational DB (SQL Server, MySQL, SQLITE)

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, api, sqlite

I'm using a tool called Teamwork to manage my team's projects.
The have an online API that consists of JSON files that are accessible with authorisation
https://developer.teamwork.com/projects/introduction/welcome-to-the-teamwork-projects-api
I would like to be able to convert this online data to an sql db so i can create custom reports for my management.
I can't seem to find anything ready to do that.
I need a strategy to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to program, this should be pretty straightforward.

In Python, for example, you could:

1. Come up with a SQL schema that maps to the JSON data objects you want to store. Create it in a database of your choice.
2. Use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to download the JSON resources, if you don't already have them on your system.
3. Convert each JSON resource to a python data structure using `json.loads`.
4. Connect to your database server using the appropriate Python library for your database. e.g., [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/).
5. Iterate over the python data, inserting rows into the database as appropriate. This is essentially the JSON-to-Tables mapping from step 1 made procedural.

If you are not looking to do this in code, you should be able to use an open-source ETL tool to do this transformation. At LinkedIn a coworker of mine used to use [Talend Data Integration](https://www.talend.com/products/data-integration/data-integration-open-studio/) for solid ETL work of a very similar nature (JSON to SQL). He was very fond of it and I respected his opinion, so I figured I should mention it, although I have zero experience of it myself.